# QuickSort never stops

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm trying to implement the Quick Sort algorithm, but when I run it never stops, resulting with a `StackOverflowException`.

(I know that using the two stacks to rearange the array, as I do, it is not the most efficient way, but at this time this is not so important.)

```
 private static void quickSort(int[] a, int start, int end) {
        if (start >= end) {
            return;
        }

        int pivot = a[start];
        Stack<Integer> left = new Stack<Integer>();
        Stack<Integer> right = new Stack<Integer>();

        for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
            if (a[i] < pivot) {
                left.push(a[i]);
            } else {
                right.push(a[i]);
            }
        }

        int arrayIndex = 0;
        int middle = 0;

        while (left.size() > 0) {
            a[arrayIndex++] = left.pop();
        }

        middle = arrayIndex;
        a[arrayIndex++] = pivot;

        while (right.size() > 0) {
            a[arrayIndex++] = right.pop();
        }

        quickSort(a, start, middle - 1);
        quickSort(a, middle + 1, end);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 int arrayIndex = 0;
```

must be replaced by

```
 int arrayIndex = start;
```

Comment: It will still overflow on equal values. (Using Stack cause reversing order during recursion that saves us from overflow when there are no equal values in array)

Comment: Thank you! You are right, changing `arrayIndex=start` fixes it. But pivot is not pushed on to the `right` stack, because the pivot is always `a[start]`, but the iteration begins from `start+1`.

Comment: I didn't see the start+1 first time round. removed the second correction!